# Getting a relay not permitted error with Exim4

Tags: django, smtp, exim, exim4

I am currently getting the following error:

```
2019-06-28 14:45:41 no host name found for IP address 192.168.X.X
2019-06-28 14:45:41 H=(cabc5b9f0d80) [192.168.X.X] F=<noreply@X.X.X.X> rejected RCPT <example@exmple.com>: relay not permitted
```

My update-exim4.conf.conf looks as follows:

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='smarthost'
dc_other_hostnames='example.com; localhost.localdomain; localhost'
dc_local_interfaces='127.0.0.1 ; ::1'
dc_readhost='example.com'
dc_relay_domains='*'
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets='smtpserver.url'
dc_smarthost='example.com'
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='false'
dc_hide_mailname=''
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='mail_spool'
```

When I run echo `"Subject: sendmail test" | sendmail -v example@exmple.com`, I receive the email which leads me to believe the config is fine, HOWEVER, when I attempt to send the email via my django app that is hosted on the same server I get the above error. My app conf looks as follows:

```
EMAIL_HOST = "example.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_NAME = "exmaple"
EMAIL_ALIAS = "noreply@X.X.X.X"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ""
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ""
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
EMAIL_BATCH_SIZE = 50 
EMAIL_BATCH_PAUSE = 300
```

The error in the app's logs is as follows:

```
Task scheduler.tasks.workflow_send_email[740b2e55-896e-4a75-9e19-4fa5562783e2] raised unexpected: SMTPRecipientsRefused({'example@example.com': (550, b'relay not permitted')},)
...
smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'example@example.com': (550, b'relay not permitted')}
```

My app also happens to be dockerised!

Answer (score 0):

Updated my configuration to look as follows:

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='smarthost'
dc_other_hostnames='example.com;'
dc_local_interfaces=''
dc_readhost=''
dc_relay_domains='*'
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets='170.17.0.0/16' #allow docker
dc_smarthost='your.smtp.server'
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='false'
dc_hide_mailname=''
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='mail_spool'
```

Then in my env.py:

```
EMAIL_HOST = "172.17.0.1" #docker bridge
```

This allowed for incoming emails to be relayed.